# freemarker replace & and &amp;

Tags: javascript, html, regex, freemarker

I have a problem with Freemarker.
I want to remove all the special characters from this sentence, and also some similar sentences in the future:

> BLA BLA RANDOM  &, RANDOM BLA

In particular, the &, but the platform also uses HTML, so with the below code:

```
> <#assign text1 = name?replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9. ]", "",'r')>
>${text1}
```

I get:

> BLA BLA RANDOM  amp RANDOM BLA

i'm trying also something like this that it remove the &amp but how do i add also some special like !@#$%^90 to be removed in case will be in there?

```
> <#assign text1 = name?replace('&amp;,', '')>
```

Comment: Try wrapping the code with `<#outputformat "undefined">`/`</#outputformat>`. I guess your current output format is set to HTML, please check that with `${.output_format}`

Comment: ${.output_format} i get undefined  / also with     ><#outputformat "undefined">/</#outputformat> i get the same result

Comment: I suppose if all else fails you could just go through it again and replace `\bamp\b` with `""`

Comment: You should only run a regex against *plain text*, not *escaped* one. You need to check where the string is escaped, or how to disable the feature.

Comment: Simply removing special characters is a strange thing to do... are you sure this is what they want from you?

Comment: :D yes pretty sure on what should i do. my doubt was if in the future i will get something like
  `BLA BLA RANDOM & RANDOM@#$ BLA`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what characters or character sequences you need to filter out, but based on what you already have, maybe this:

```
${s?replace('&[a-zA-Z]+;', '', 'r')?replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9. ]', '', 'r')}
```

So this first removes things like `&amp;`, then only keeps the "safe" characters.

But, at least in principle this is incomplete, because HTML can contain things like `&#65;`, which just means `A`, and so it shouldn't be removed, but replaced with `A`... Or, it may contains tags like `<b>foo</b>`, which then should be converted to `foo`, not `bfoob`. Not sure if you need to handle such things, but if so, the string needs to be converted to plain text, which is not a trivial thing and FreeMarker has no built-in for that.

Comment: thanks,but apparently i cannot replace on the printout, but only in the variable...i get some freemarker error

Comment: sorry ignore my previous comment with your code i was still getting the &amp i slightly mod like this and looks it does what i need:
`?replace("&,|[^a-zA-Z0-9.]", " ", 'r')>`

Comment: @crasion Ah, I have forgotten the `+` before the `;`... see updated answer. (I don't think the `&,|` thing in your comment works.)